# Using native code functions as JavaScript objects in WebKit

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit, native, jquery-lint

I'm unable to use native code functions as JavaScript objects in WebKit-based browsers. Is it impossible to alias these functions directly?

This is easiest to explain by example, so here is what I am running in the Developer Tools console:

```
console.warn;
// Outputs:
// function warn() {
//     [native code]
// }

console.warn("console.warn");
// Outputs: "console.warn"

var _c = console;
_c.warn("_c.warn");
// Outputs: "_c.warn"

var _w = console.warn;
_w("_w");
// Outputs: "TypeError: Type error" on Safari/WebKit (Mac)
// Outputs: "TypeError: Illegal invocation" on Chrome (Mac)

var _w2 = function () { console.warn.apply(console, arguments); }
_w2("_w2");
// Outputs: "w2"
```

---

This issue came up as I tried to use [jQuery Lint](http://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Lint) in Safari; it uses the following approach to prevent breakage if window.console does not exist:

```
_console = {
    warn: window.console && console.warn || function(){},
    ...
}

_console.warn("some error");
```

Here's my temporary workaround:

```
if((jQuery.browser.safari || jQuery.browser.webkit) && window.console) {
    jQuery.LINT.level = 3;
    jQuery.LINT.console = {
        warn: function() { console.warn.apply(console, arguments); },
        group: function() { console.group.apply(console, arguments); },
        groupEnd: function() { console.groupEnd(); },
        groupCollapsed: function() { console.group.apply(console, arguments); },
        log: function() { console.log.apply(console, arguments); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't alias *any* methods in JavaScript, native or not, WebKit or not.

When you say `var _w = console.warn;`, you are stripping `warn` away from its owner object `console` and treating it as a standalone function. When you call it, it gets no `this` reference to the `console`, so it fails to work.

You may find this unusual from how bound methods work in other languages, but that's just how JavaScript method calls are designed: the `this` reference is passed to a function based solely on what `owner` is in `owner.method()` (or `owner['method']()`). If the function is called alone without an owner, `this` is set to the `window` object and the method will most likely fall over.

To get around this and pass in a proper `this`, you must either use `method.call` (or `method.apply`) explicitly as described by @slebetman, or make your own bound function using a closure like `var _w= function() { console.warn.apply(console, arguments) };` or, in ECMAScript Fifth Edition, `method.bind(owner)`.

Comment: Oddly, newer versions of Firebug don't mind if you alias `console`'s methods.

Comment: Well okay, I lied a bit. :-) Of course it depends on the implementation; it is naturally possible to make a function that can be called back without caring what its `this` is, in which case aliasing the method into a variable will work... although clearly it's not something you can rely on. (Further, for non-native ‘host objects’ provided by the browser all bets are off.)

Answer (score 2):

That should be:

```
console.warn.apply(console,arguments);
```

The first parameter to apply is the value of **this** to pass into the `warn` method.

Comment: Thanks; I've updated my question to correct this oversight. It solves the majority of the issues I was having, but I'll hold off a bit longer to see whether anyone has some good info about native functions in WebKit.